# How do I stop  XML Copy Editor from crashing when opening a file?

Tags: text-editor, editor, xml

I tried installing XML Copy Editor, and whenever I try to open an XML file in it, it crashes. It seems like it just shuts off, as though I clicked close, because it doesn't generate and error log. How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 3):

It's known issue: [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xml-copy-editor/forums/forum/475215/topic/4711144)

You'll have to build it from source, or wait for it author.
And I'm not quite sure, but I think you'll need 1.2.0.6 version, and not the latest, which wont build because of dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Got same problem for me below commands works as a fix (on Ubuntu 12.04):

```
mkdir ~/compilexmlcopyeditor && cd ~/compilexmlcopyeditor
sudo apt-get purge xmlcopyeditor
sudo apt-get build-dep xmlcopyeditor
sudo apt-get source xmlcopyeditor
cd xmlcopyeditor-1.2.0.6
sudo dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -us -b
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

from: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xmlcopyeditor/+bug/967087

Comment: It works! Now I can open a file without crashing.